# react chart js 2 ширина баров

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

всем привет подскажите пожалуйста react chart js 2  как мне установить ширину баров чтобы они на всю ширину размещались  barThickness: 'flex' это не помогло[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
                        {
                        label: `Люк открыт ${value.modified_at.split('T')[1].split('.')[0]}`,
                        backgroundColor: '#dc3545',
                        borderColor: '#dc3545',
                        data: dataArrGraf
                    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31188888/4794368

Comment: Не помогло написал параметр но не помогло